# Replacing col name and row value using an external list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(column1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("text1", "text3"
), class = "factor"), column2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("text1", 
"text2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("column1", "column2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

And I would like to replace the value of cells based on the list:

```
    dput(df2)
structure(list(current_values = structure(1:5, .Label = c("column1", 
"column2", "text1", "text2", "text3"), class = "factor"), new_values = structure(1:5, .Label = c("c1", 
"c2", "t1", "t2", "t3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("current_values", 
"new_values"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

and have as final out put this:

```
dput(finalout)
structure(list(c1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("t1", "t3"), class = "factor"), 
    c2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("t1", "t2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Is it possible to make it also in the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using `match`:

```
res = apply(df1,2,function(x) df2[match(x,df2[,1]),2])
colnames(res) = df2[match(colnames(res),df2[,1]),2]
```

This returns:

```
      c1   c2  
[1,] "t1" "t2"
[2,] "t3" "t1"
```